# Grammatically correct use of whom vs who

Tags: grammar

Which of the following is correct?

> Franz did not like his teacher M. Hamel either; whom he felt was strict and cranky.
>
> Vs
>
> Franz did not like his teacher M. Hamel either; who he felt was strict and cranky.

I feel the former is more appropriate than the latter but book says it with "whom". Can someone clear up the rules of who vs whom again?

Comment: It's "whom," but lots of English speakers would say "who."  Also, the sentence isn't grammatical.  It should be: "Franz did not like his teacher M. Hamel, whom he felt was strict and cranky, either."

Comment: But do try the search box. This has come up often.

Comment: Nancy's right. The rule is that 'who' is used to refer to the * subject * of a verb or proposition; 'whom' is used to refer to the * object * of a verb or proposition.   She hit him. Who hit him? She did. Whom did she hit? Him. Your sentence could also be rewritten: "Neither did Franz like his teacher M. Hamel, whom he felt was strict and cranky."

Comment: @Nancy Nope, it has to be *who*. You cannot have *whom* be the subject of *was strict and cranky*. Q.E.D.